# why am i receiving this error for a simple compare? Invalid parameter number- Yii

Tags: yii

I am not sure why am I receiving this error. I've been doing this, doesn't seem to have an error elsewhere. Why is this showing an error?
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens.

in model:

```
public function read()
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('status_receiver',"N",true);
    $data = new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria,));

    return $data->getData();
}

public function defaultScope()
    {

        $id = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
        return array(
                'condition'=>"id ='".$id ."'",
                'params' => array(':id' => $id ),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that error is in this method?

Comment: the only thing that may be in conflict with this is my default scope (updated). I have it in my other models, those seem to be working fine. I don't have anything else written in this model...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    return array(
            'condition'=>"id =:id",
            'params' => array('id' => $id ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return array(
                'condition'=>"id = :id",
                'params' => array(':id' => $id ),
        );
```